# Why payout rates from income annuities largely depend on corporate bond yields?

Tags: annuity, fixed-income, corporate-bonds

Why is that payout rates from income annuities largely depend on corporate bond yields? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I grant the premise. Where did you see this claim?

Comment: I'd agree that when corporate yields are higher, fixed income annuities will be higher but corporate securities are not the root cause of that. Many  securities are higher when interest rates are higher (corporate bonds, preferred stocks, Treasuries, and even call options).  They all compete for the income seeking dollar.  Interest rates is the culprit.

Comment: @BobBaerker What type of interest rates are you talking about? (e.g. fed fund rate, short-term, long-term.. etc)?

Comment: For interest sensitive annuities, insurance companies tend to follow the 10-year Treasury rate.

Comment: @BobBaerker Thanks. Any examples of interest sensitive annuities?

Comment: Google "How Interest Rates Impact Annuities" for detailed explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Insurance companies back a lot of annuities with corporate bond investment, so it makes sense that your income is pegged to corporate bond yield. (A bit chicken-and-egg though in terms of whether the peg determines the investment or the reverse...)

Similarly, variable and various index annuities are backed with stock index options among other things.

Comment: Do you know why insurance companies back a lot of annuities with corporate bond investment and variable and various index annuities are backed with stock index options?

Comment: The basis of some index annuities is a complicated option position.  The insurance company creates it and then sells you a policy based on its potential gains and losses.  Your potential risk/reward is less than what the option position generates and that is the insurance company's profit.  It's not quite arbitrage but that would be the closest analogy that I can think of.

Comment: @HelloDarkWorld Typical annuities promise a relatively stable stream of income, much like the coupon payments of a bond. So it is natural from an asset-liability management perspective to take policyholder's premium and invest in bonds. Similarly, equity-linked annuities have return features that can be mimicked by holding certain stock index derivatives positions.